# OSError: pytest: reading from stdin while output is captured! Consider using `-s`

Tags: python, pytest

While running a particular unittest with pytest, it occasionally fails with this error (mentioned in the title) and from the stack trace it happens on the line

```
    self = <_pytest.capture.DontReadFromInput object at 0x0000024AD00E7668>
args = ()

    def read(self, *args):
        raise IOError(
>           "pytest: reading from stdin while output is captured!  Consider using `-s`."
        )
E       OSError: pytest: reading from stdin while output is captured!  Consider using `-s`.
```

Error location code：

```
def setUp(self):
    desired_caps = {}
    id = input("please input your number：")
```

Comment: Why are you reading input inside your test's `setUp` function? That's not how unit testing is supposed to be used.

Comment: But when I used it before, there was no problem at all, until today

Comment: You weren't using `pytest` to run the tests before, supposedly. Automated tests shouldn't require user input that interrupts the test run; use command line arguments or environment variables for passing user input.

Comment: I've also seen this happen when I tried to have one test function invoke another test. I thought I could 'recycle' some state machine tests to get the FSM into some particular state, but... that generated the error mentioned by the OP. The fix was to farm out the common bits to helper functions in the suite whose names do *not* start with `test` (and may also contain `assert` statements) and then have my tests leverage those to 'steer themselves' into the desired start state.

Answer (score 2):

try to extract the functions into a separate file, call them in the file and run the pytest with the -s flag like this
pytest FILENAME -s